# How to return Dialogue fragments result values

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I created a `DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment` and I am calling the `DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment` from `MainActivity`.

My problem is, how can I send the `DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment` result values to `MainActivity`.

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonid) {

        DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment dateandTimePickerDialogueFragment = new DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment();
        dateandTimePickerDialogueFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment");
    }
}
```

**DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment:**

```
public class DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return displayDateDialogPicker(getActivity());
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    private Dialog displayDateDialogPicker(Context context) {

        int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(context,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        int mymonth = monthOfYear + 1;
                        String mmmMonth = "", mmDate = "";
                        if (mymonth > 0 && mymonth < 10) {

                            mmmMonth = "0" + mymonth;

                        } else {

                            mmmMonth = "" + mymonth;
                        }

                        if (dayOfMonth > 0 && dayOfMonth < 10) {
                            mmDate = "0" + dayOfMonth;
                        } else {

                            mmDate = "" + dayOfMonth;
                        }
                        //YYYY-MM-DD
                        String finalDate = year + "-" + (mmmMonth) + "-" + mmDate;

                        Intent intentData = new Intent();
                        intentData.putExtra("Date", finalDate);

                        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intentData);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpd.show();
        return dpd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write a method to update your class variables to get results?

Answer (score 0):

In your `DialogFragment` you can make interface for this

replace full code with below code

```
public class DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment extends DialogFragment {
public static interface OnCompleteListener {
    public abstract void onComplete(String time);
}

private OnCompleteListener mListener;
// make sure the Activity implemented it

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        this.mListener = (OnCompleteListener) activity;
    } catch (final ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnCompleteListener");
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return displayDateDialogPicker(getActivity());
}

/**
 * @param context
 */
private Dialog displayDateDialogPicker(Context context) {
    mListener = (OnCompleteListener)getActivity();
    int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(context,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    int mymonth = monthOfYear + 1;
                    String mmmMonth = "", mmDate = "";
                    if (mymonth > 0 && mymonth < 10) {

                        mmmMonth = "0" + mymonth;

                    } else {

                        mmmMonth = "" + mymonth;
                    }

                    if (dayOfMonth > 0 && dayOfMonth < 10) {
                        mmDate = "0" + dayOfMonth;
                    } else {

                        mmDate = "" + dayOfMonth;
                    }
                    //YYYY-MM-DD
                    String finalDate = year + "-" + (mmmMonth) + "-" + mmDate;


                    mListener.onComplete(finalDate);
                   // getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intentData);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();
    return dpd;
}
}
```

Now in Your Activity you can `implements DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment.OnCompleteListener` and import interface's method and in this method you can get your data

```
 @Override
public void onComplete(String time) {
    Log.d("TAG", time.toString());
}
```

Comment: i am getting exception's like                                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

Comment: try to first check `Intent` is null or not

Answer (score 0):

While not use an interface that holds a method or a valueType on your DialogFragment and before return dpd, insert that dpd in that variable interface and implement that interface on your MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to set up an Interface listener.

In your Dialog Fragment:

```
    public interface DateandTimeListener {
         public void OnDateTimeSelected(String date);
    }

    private static DateandTimeListener mListener;

    //Your activity will call this. Passing its context 'this' as the listener.
    public void setDateandTimeListener(DateandTimeListener listener){
         mListener = listener;
    }
```

Then in your onDateSet:

```
 public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
 ....                        
 String finalDate = year + "-" + (mmmMonth) + "-" + mmDate;
 mListener.OnDateTimeSelected(finalDate);

 ....
 }
```

In your MainActivity:

Make sure you implement the listener.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DateandTimePickerDialogueFragment.DateandTimeListener
```

This will force you to override the `OnDateTimeSelected` callback function in the activity. From there you will get the finalDate string that is returned from your dialog.

Also in your activity make sure you call `setDateandTimeListener(this)` to set the listener

Hope that helps!